# How to write sub query using linq in mvc5?

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am writing my sub query using linq in my application. I wrote my sql sub-query in sql server. When I execute this query in SQL Server the result give perfect and the sql query will be like

My SQL Server:

```
 select Row_Number() Over(OrderBy Mmname) as Sno,Mmname,Mmcardno,Mmdob,MmEmail,(Select SUM(MSSRNETAMT) from MSCAS where MSCAS.MSSFORMNO = MSMEM.MmCardno and MSCAS.MSSRBILLDT between '01/01/2016' and '30/12/2016') Billopen,(Select SUM(MSSRNETAMT) from MSCAS where MSCAS.MSSFORMNO = MSMEM.MmCardno and MSCAS.MSSRBILLDT between '01/01/2016' and '30/12/2016') BillForm,Mmredpv,Msdval,Mmcontact,Mmdate,Mmaddr,MmCuser,MmCuserdt,Mmusercd,
  Mmuser,Mmuserdt,Cast(Mmcntrn as int ) as Mmcntr from MSMEM inner join MSSCHEDET   on MSMEM.Mschuid = MSSCHEDET.MSDID
```

My linq query

```
             Var query = (from Ms in db.msmems join Mss in db. Msschedet on Ms. Mechuid equals mss. MSDID select new 
         {
            name = Ms. Mmname, 
           Billopen = (from mc in db. MSCAS where Ms.      Mmcardno = mc. Mssformno) select mc.MSSRNETAMT);
     }):
```

This only I tried but I am getting error in bill open it is amount  in that I am getting error

This is my SQL query. I tried to convert this sql query in linq. But I am failed many times, I got an error.

Comment: What Linq code do you have, and what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this?  Without understanding your table structure better, I took a shot at optimizing this.  Is there no reason that you couldn't do a second join to your `MSCAS` table?

```
var query = (from Ms in db.msmems
             join Mss in db.Msschedet on Ms.Mechuid equals mss.MSDID
             join Mc in db.MSCAS on Ms.Mmcardno equals Mc.Mssformno
             select new { 
                         name = Ms.Mmname, 
                         Billopen = Mc.where(x=>x.MSSRBILLDT >= '01-01-2016' and x.MSSRBILLDT <= '12-30-2016').Sum(z=>z.MSSRNETAMT)
                        }
            );
```